# Application crashing due to springboot error

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im facing below error after deploying my api. upgraded my api to spring 2.6.4 and junit 5, after deploymetn facing the below issue.Im facing below error after deploying my api. upgraded my api to spring 2.6.4 and junit 5, after deploymetn facing the below issue.

```
[2022-11-23 09:21:17.380] [BGM-sf-api-2-0-1-10-2-g7vz2] [ERROR] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] [{}] - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'BGMRequestsController' defined in URL [jar:file:/api/runtime/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycomp/api/fetch/BGM/controller/BGMRequestsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'BGMRequestsServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/api/runtime/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/herculesimpl/BGMRequestsServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fetchAuthTokenGatewayImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/api/runtime/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycomp/api/fetch/BGM/gateway/impl/fetchAuthTokenGatewayImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mycomp.api.core.web.util.RestClient' available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [BGMRequestsGatewayImpl, getRestClientUtil, restClientBean, serviceMeshRestClient]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
    at 

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at com.mycomp.api.Application.main(Application.java:48) ~[classes!/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app.jar:?]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'BGMRequestsServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/api/runtime/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/herculesimpl/BGMRequestsServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fetchAuthTokenGatewayImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/api/runtime/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycomp/api/fetch/BGM/gateway/impl/fetchAuthTokenGatewayImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mycomp.api.core.web.util.RestClient' available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [BGMRequestsGatewayImpl, getRestClientUtil, restClientBean, serviceMeshRestClient]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fetchAuthTokenGatewayImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/api/runtime/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycomp/api/fetch/BGM/gateway/impl/fetchAuthTokenGatewayImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mycomp.api.core.web.util.RestClient' available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [BGMRequestsGatewayImpl, getRestClientUtil, restClientBean, serviceMeshRestClient]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mycomp.api.core.web.util.RestClient' available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [BGMRequestsGatewayImpl, getRestClientUtil, restClientBean, serviceMeshRestClient]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.determinePrimaryCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1673) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.determineAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1364) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        ... 27 more
    [2022-11-23 09:22:56.
```

Comment: First thing first, I suggest you to edit and format your question to have a better readability.
Secondly, it seems to be multiple `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`s that seems to derive from a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` in your `com.mycomp.api.core.web.util.RestClient`

Comment: apologies, couldnt post the formatted version, its was showing formating exception, so posted as it is.. And thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple instances of RestClient beans defined in your configuration, and spring can't tell which of them you want to Autowire. when you annotate with `@Bean` give it a name as a parameter and then you need to add `@Qualifier` annotations to all autowired members of the same class (or extending) as RestClient, and
specify which bean name you want for each autowired member.